# R Shiny: "Error in $.shinyoutput: Reading from shinyoutput object is not allowed."

Tags: r, shiny

I'm making a shiny app in which the user can generate tabs that display different dataframes based on the number of tabs made. For example, in the code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)

ui <- navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), 
                 title = "",
                 id = "tabs",
                 position = "static-top",
                 tabPanel(title = "Plus",
                          icon = icon("plus"))
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  count <- reactiveValues(value = 0)

  observeEvent(input$tabs, {
    if (input$tabs == "Plus"){
      count$value <- count$value + 1
      id = paste0("Base ", count$value)
      insertTab(inputId = "tabs",
                tabPanel(title = id,
                         fluidRow(
                           column(width = 12,
                                  dataTableOutput(outputId = paste0("data", count$value))
                           )
                         )), target = "Plus", 
                position = "before",
                select = TRUE)}
  })


    output$data1 <- renderDataTable({
      mtcars[1, 1:2]
    })


    output$data2 <- renderDataTable({
      mtcars[2, 1:2]
    })


    output$data3 <- renderDataTable({
      mtcars[3, 1:2]
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

you can see that the user can add a tab and that tab 1 will generate the first row of the dataframe, tab 2 the second row of the dataframe, etc.

However, there is a limit to this method: I have to write the code for all rows that the user can potentially display. In order to reduce the length of the code while not limiting the user to a certain number of rows, I would like to automate that.

I would like to create a function that will display the right row in each tab. Therefore, I make a function that creates a different dataframe given its argument and I include this function in `observeEvent`, so that clicking on "Plus" creates a new tab and fills it with the right dataframe.

Below is the new code (the `ui` part is the same):

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  treat <- function(i){
    output$paste0("data", i) <- renderDataTable({
      mtcars[i, 1:2]
    })
  }

  count <- reactiveValues(value = 1)

  observeEvent(input$tabs, {
    if (input$tabs == "Plus"){
      count$value <- count$value + 1
      id = paste0("Base ", count$value)
      insertTab(inputId = "tabs",
                tabPanel(title = id,
                         fluidRow(
                           column(width = 12,
                                  dataTableOutput(outputId = paste0("data", count$value))
                           )
                         )), target = "Plus", 
                position = "before",
                select = TRUE)

      treat(count$value)
      }
  })
```

The problem is that I get this error:

> Error in <-: target of assignment expands to non-language object

Searching for solutions, I find that I need to use the `assign` function. So I change my function to:

```
  treat <- function(i){
    assign(output$paste0("data", i), renderDataTable({
      mtcars[i, 1:2]
    })
    )
  }
```

But since I am now using a shiny output in a function, I have the error:

> Error in $.shinyoutput: Reading from shinyoutput object is not allowed.

How could I bypass this error to obtain what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: I just need to replace `output$paste0("data", i)` by `output[[paste0("data", i)]]`.

Hope this will help somebody